# Why to avoid using ByteStream much in Java

Tags: java, io, stream

We shouldn't use byte Stream as Sun Doc says -

> actually it represents a kind of low-level I/O that you should avoid.

What is actually low-level I/O and what is exact problem using byte stream.

Comment: "Low-level I/O" means that it's a lot more fiddly and complicated to use -- and easier to mess up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the [Java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/bytestreams.html) say:

> CopyBytes seems like a normal program, but it actually represents a
>   kind of low-level I/O that you should avoid. Since xanadu.txt contains
>   character data, the best approach is to use character streams, as
>   discussed in the next section. There are also streams for more
>   complicated data types. Byte streams should only be used for the most
>   primitive I/O.

The byte streams give you access to the file as it is.  Just the bytes.  No interpration of any kind.  That means no character set conversion, no handling of ints or floats in binary or ascii representation, no dealing with byte orders, or any of that.  The higher level streams provide some of these.

Of course a program that copies a file is actually a pretty good example of something that needs a raw byte stream, because it doesn't need or want to do any kind of intepretation of the data; it just wants to copy it verbatim.

So what the really mean is, use byte streams if you think you need them, but be sure you know what you are doing :)

Answer (score 2):

The suggestion is in the context of reading a text file that is discussed in the tutorial. For that purpose it is better to use character streams to handle character set translation properly:

> The Java platform stores character values using Unicode conventions.
>   Character stream I/O automatically translates this internal format to
>   and from the local character set.
>
> A program that uses character streams in place of byte streams
>   automatically adapts to the local character set and is ready for
>   internationalization — all without extra effort by the programmer.